Next steps for finding the extremal of a function that is independent to $t$ (Using $\dot{x} = \tan\chi$ substitution)
I am asked to find the extremal of the following function:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\frac{(1+\dot{x}^2)^\frac{1}{2}}{x} \: dt
\end{align*}
With the boundary conditions of $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)=\sqrt3$
Since the integrand is independent of $t$, instead of the Euler-Lagrange equation, we can use the following instead:
$${\ f} -\dot{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}} = c
$$
where $c$ is a constant.
According to Enid Pinch's textbook - page 40 of "Optimal Control and the Calculus of Variations" - we can use the substitution $\dot{x} = \tan\chi$, a trick to solve the differential equation that arises from the problem.
The final answer is supposed to be:
$${x} = (4-(t-2)^2)^\frac{1}{2}$$
Here are my efforts so far:
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1+\dot{x}^2} - \dot{x}^2(1+\dot{x}^2)^{-1/2}}{x} = c $$
After doing the substitution we get:
$$cx = \frac{1}{\cos\chi} - \tan^2\chi\cos\chi
= \cos\chi$$
$$x = \frac{\cos\chi}{c}$$ and since $\dot{x} = \tan\chi$ we can write $$\dot{x} = -\dot{\chi}\frac{\sin\chi}{c}$$ so $$c = -\dot{\chi}\cos\chi$$
If I'm not mistaken, integrating relatively to $\chi$ gives:
$$
c\chi + l = \sin \chi
$$
And I'm not sure how to proceed from here, in order to get things back to the $t$ and $x$ parameters.
Any kind of guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

What boundary conditions?

Oh you're right, I completely forgot to mention it! Just edited the post with the included boundary conditions, even coded the rest of my answer instead of including a picture :)

From $c=-\dot \chi \cos \chi$ we have $\sin \chi = ct+b$. But then I don't get the answer you claimed.

That "final answer" doesn't satisfy $x(0)=0$ or $x(1)=\sqrt{3}$.

You're right; I had misread the final answer. Just re-checked the textbook and edited the post. My apologies

Integrating $c=-\dot{\chi}\cos\chi$ with respect to $t$ one finds
$$
ct+b=-\sin\chi. \tag{1}
$$
Squaring both sides of $(1)$, and using the relation $cx=\cos\chi$, one obtains
$$
(ct+b)^2=\sin^2\chi=1-\cos^2\chi=1-c^2x^2
$$
$$
\implies x=\pm\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{1-(ct+b)^2}. \tag{2}
$$
Now use the boundary conditions $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)=\sqrt{3}$ to determine the constants $c$ and $b$.

If my calculations are correct then $c = -\frac{1}{2}$ for $b = 1$ and $c = \frac{1}{2}$ for $b = -1$, because $c$ can't equal $0$, otherwise we wouldn't have an extremal in the first place. Thank you!
